# DBNull exception in visual basic 2010 database

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I am working on a customer database and vb.net form consisting in a `datagridview`.

I consists of 3 columns :

```
customer_id, customer_name, customer_Notes
```

I have created two functions to facilitate my job, one for inserting data from the `datagridview` to my MS Access database and the other for updating the data showed on the datagridview.

Well , I face a problem. I got an error message concerning conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'string'.

The error message occurs in case of missing to fill at least one of the datagridview columns whether I insert or update one of the following columns:

```
customer_id, customer_name, customer_Notes
```

Otherwise everything is fine.

I searched on the web before I asked my question here and I knew that I shall test DBNull first but i failed to learn the right way to do this.

**Insert** function:

```
 Public Sub insert_customer(ByVal customer_id As Integer, ByVal customer_name As String, ByVal customer_address As String, ByVal customer_phone As String, ByVal customer_notes As String)
        Try
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("insert into tblCustomers (CustomerID , CustomerName , CustomerNotes) values (@CustomerID,@CustomerName ,  @CustomerNotes) ", conn_Access)

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = customer_id
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerName", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = customer_name

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerNotes", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = customer_notes

            conn_Access.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            conn_Access.Close()
            cmd = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
  End Sub
```

**Update** function:

```
 Public Sub update_customer(ByVal customer_name As String, ByVal customer_notes As String, ByVal Customer_ID2 As Integer)
        Try
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("update  tblCustomers set CustomerName= @CustomerName , CustomerNotes= @CustomerNotes where CustomerID = @CustomerID2 ", conn_Access)

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = customer_name

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerNotes", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = customer_notes
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID2", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Customer_ID2

            conn_Access.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            conn_Access.Close()

            cmd = Nothing

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

  End Sub
```

Private Sub Btn_save_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btn_save.Click
        'update
        'اول عمود 
        Try

```
        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2

            With DataGridView1.Rows(i)
                'اول عمود 

                If count_customer_id_from_customers(.Cells(0).Value) = 1 Then
                    'update

                    update_customer(.Cells(1).Value, .Cells(2).Value, .Cells(3).Value, .Cells(4).Value, .Cells(0).Value)

                Else
                    'insert
                    insert_customer(.Cells(0).Value, .Cells(1).Value, .Cells(2).Value, .Cells(3).Value, .Cells(4).Value)
                End If
            End With
        Next
```

load_Customers()

```
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try


End Sub
```

Any Help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: What database are you using? (There is no database called "visual basic 2010 database".)

Comment: Check if dbnull is like this:
    if customer_name = DBNull.Value then
        'do something
    else
        ' do some other thing
    end if

Comment: Can you check If the columns are `NOT NULL`? This could be the problem.

Comment: Is CustomerID an auto increment field in Access? If so remove it from your Insert statement. You can test your arguments with `String.IsNullOrEmpty(customer_name)` and take action where necessary.

Comment: @ richard 
thanks for reply , i use my access database named "free sales.accdb" but does it matter my database name in my problem sir

Comment: a great thanks for u all ,i am as a new user in this great site really benefited from ur participating

Comment: i will try out ur  ideas and come back again